# $.mobile.changePage not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use `$.mobile.changePage` but it doesn't work.
 Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css">
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="p1">
            <div data-role="header"><h2>DKT</h2></div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div id="sw1"></div>
                <div id="sw2"></div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">...</div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $.mobile.changePage("#qu");
        </script>
        <div data-role="page" id="qu">
            <div data-role="header"><h2>DKT</h2></div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a"><button>Nein</button></div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b"><button>Kaufen</button></div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm already getting the error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'i.trigger')`

I allready tried to change to "http://www.google.com" : still getting the same error

**Edit:**

### Thanks to all. But the problem was actually in another part of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your jquery code in a `document.ready` handler, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.mobile.changePage("#qu");
});
```

Because otherwise you are not giving time for the DOM to be loaded and so the `#qu` element is not present when trying to get it.

Comment: There is a risk when using `$(document).ready()` in jQuery Mobile. You should probably bind on `pagecreate`, `pagebeforeshow` or something likt that.

Answer (score 0):

Add Your script after

```
 <div data-role="page" id="qu">
```

OR after end of body tag

like this :

```
 <script>
             $.mobile.changePage("#qu");
         </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css">
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="p1">
            <div data-role="header"><h2>DKT</h2></div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div id="sw1"></div>
                <div id="sw2"></div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">...</div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('#p1').live('pageshow', function(event){
                $.mobile.changePage("#qu");            
            });
        </script>
        <div data-role="page" id="qu">
            <div data-role="header"><h2>DKT</h2></div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a"><button>Nein</button></div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b"><button>Kaufen</button></div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In your code the `$.mobile.changePage("#qu");` is called before the dom is initiated.  You can use many other events such as `pagebeforeshow`, `pagecreate` etc. Check the jQuery Mobile [documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/) for more information.

Make sure you are not using `$(doucment).ready(function(){});` as well.